# Login to many users simultaneously from root with su on the same Linux system

Tags: sudo, su

I have several users on CentOS6 who use the same software installed in their home directories with user's permissions. For example:

```
/home/bob/myserver
/home/alex/myserver
```

where myserver is the software I want to update, e.g.

```
su bob
cd ~/myserver
git fetch
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

I want to do something like this:

```
(1) su bob,alex
(2) cd ~/myserver; git fetch; git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

I don't want to login to each user one by one.

In other words, I want something like `cluster ssh` but for user accounts not for machines.

Comment: Well, you could do `cssh bob@localhost alex@localhost`, etc. :D Why not loop over usernames? `for user in bob alex; do sudo -iu $user sh -c 'cd ~/myserver; git fetch; git merge FETCH_HEAD'; done`?

Comment: Yes, probably that's the way.